# How to receive click event in activity from a recycler-view adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-recyclerview, android-service-binding

EDITED on 14.11.2018:

I would like to simplify my question, how can I receive a click event in the activity from the Fragment which contains a recycler-view and it has an adapter which handels the click event?

The application looks the following:
[image]

---

I am working on an application which is using BLE service (based on the Google BLE example). I have a *DeviceScanActivity* which is successfully able to search and connects to BLE periphery, this activity starts a new activity, *DeviceControlActivity* and I bind the BLE service to it:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart: bind Service. " + mServiceConnection);
    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
    bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

In this activity I am able to send values/messages to the BLE periphery.

My application has another activity, *ManualModeActivity*.
When I start this activity I unbind the BLE service first in case of *DeviceControlActivity*:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop: BLE Service is unbind " + mServiceConnection);
    unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    BLEServiceBonded = false;
}
```

Then in the newly started activity (*ManualModeActivity*) I bind the BLE service to it, like it is done in case of the *DeviceControlActivity*.

And now starts the problem, or basically I am new in android programming and I do not know what should I do next to use the BLE service in the *ManualModeActivity*, I am searching since two days, nothing useful is found.

So let see what I am not able to do, or what makes the challenge for me.

The *ManualModeActivity* has a ViewPage with two tabs, I have created a *ManualTabPagerAdapter* which extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter, in this adapter I am loading the fragments, e.g. the *ManualDeviceFrament*. This fragment has RecyclerView, every item in the RecyclerView has a button, to handle the list and button clicks I have created a *ManualListAdapter*.
And now the challenge, if I click on the button I want to send a BLE message, but the BLE service, mBluetoothLeService is null.
I want to use the following command to send message:

```
mBluetoothLeService.writeCustomCharacteristic("Hello");
```

In case of both activities I have the following code to handle the service connection:

```
    private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
            finish();
        }
        mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
        BLEServiceBonded = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        BLEServiceBonded = false;
    }
}
```

So guys I would like to ask you to tell me some possible solutions, because I did not find any useful stuff, I am a newbee so maybe some basic knowledge is missing. If you need further details, just let me know and I will post it here.

Answer (score -1):

did you bind and unbind the service on ManualModeActivity as well?
and another thing on overriding onStop method it's better to write overridden code first than calling parent function first.
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        BLEServiceBonded = false;
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop: BLE Service is unbind " + mServiceConnection);
    }

Comment: Yes, bind and unbind is also done for that Activity, I have also found out the that Service is bind to the Activity, just I cannot call the BLE service because I call it in the recycler-view adapter and there the service is not available. And thanks for your hint regarding the Overriding.